# Two versions of angular 4+

Tags: angular

I've found these two articles 
[Article 1](https://gist.github.com/newyankeecodeshop/79f3e1348a09583faf62ed55b58d09d9) 
and [Article 2](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2017/04/04/es6-modules-support-lands-in-browsers-is-it-time-to-rethink-bundling/).

And I'm curious if there is a way to make it so that Angular CLI will develop two site versions: ES5 and ES6. According to articles it's not so difficult so I wonder if anyone made so or if there is a tool for that. For me it seems like a good opportunity to improve load speed for browsers which support ES6.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so you’re essentially writing TS code using ES2015. However, when compiled, the resulting JS code can be in ES5 or earlier. You need to define which version of JS the compiler should generate. This can be set using target option in `tsconfig.json`, Although it is possible, it is not necessarily something you would want to do. It is more common to use CommonJS or AMD modules with ES5.see [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3) and [this](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#libdts)

```
tsconfig.json

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",//es6<--
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```